# Quais critérios usar para estabelecer relações entre os elementos de programação no código?

Tags: característica-linguagem, estrutura-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, princípios-de-programação

Vou dar um exemplo.

Imagine que você tem uma classe Crud. Isso significa implementar quatro operações: Criar (create), ler (read), atualizar (update) e apagar (delete).

Você vai lá, cria uma classe `CrudQualquer` e implementa uma operação em cada função ou método.

Beleza. Poderia ter usado um array de métodos? Poderia. Faz sentido? Não muito. Por quê?

As quatro operações são fixas, não vão mudar, ter quatro métodos na classe parece algo bem estável e coeso. Todos os métodos vão usar o mesmo recurso (a saber, uma conexão de banco), que pode ser injetado na classe. Um "Crud" como unidade de código parece uma classe coesa, a princípio.

Por outro lado, isso poderia ter sido implementado como uma operação para cada classe. Faz sentido? Não sei, faz sentido uma classe ser um verbo? Talvez sim, talvez não.

Poderia ter usado um mapeamento de operações para funções? Poderia também, e faz menos sentido ainda.

Por outro lado, para rotas de uma aplicação Web um mapeamento faz sentido. O número varia, tende a crescer com o tempo, e assim o mapeamento acomoda esse crescimento, além de aparentar ser uma estrutura adequada.

Às vezes faz mais sentido ter todos os métodos que fazem algo em um lugar só, em outras faz sentido ter cada um implementado em cada classe separada. Há vantagens e desvantagens ("buscabilidade" é uma delas).

Coesão e acoplamento fazem parte desses critérios? O que mais faz? Abstração / níveis de abstração?

Java tem varargs. Em qual contexto usar? (eu sei qual, é uma dúvida retórica a título de ilustração). Outras possibilidades existem, mesmo em outras linguagens, eu não lembro delas agora, se lembrar acrescento.

O que vem de imediato são linguagens que tratam listas de parâmetros como arrays ou como listas de tamanho fixo separadas por vírgulas, isso na minha cabeça traz ambiguidade.

É muito comum em código de novatos e mesmo de programadores com mais vivência (eu incluso) estruturar o código de maneira incorreta, assim como usar estruturas de dados erradas para o que se deseja fazer, e com o tempo vão melhorando.

Tenho a impressão que, sendo a definição de "módulo" propositalmente ambígua, talvez valha um conjunto de critérios só para quaisquer nível de módulo que se tenha em foco, desde funções e seus parâmetros, até classes e pacotes/módulos do Java, por exemplo.

Não quis dar um viés de Java ou orientação a objetos, mas ficou um pouco assim. Se não precisar tudo bem, se ficar bom com o viés também tudo bem.

Comment: Isso é filosofia da ciência da computação.

Comment: Acho que não dá pra achar uma estrutura que sirva em todos os casos, cabe avaliar cada cenário específico. Creio que priorizando a simplicidade e facilidade de manutenção, o resultado será bom.